Whether and when this sum will converge?

Examine the convergence of the following sum. $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n-1)}{n!} \cdot \frac{1}{n^b}
$$ where constants:  $a\in \Bbb N$, and $b\in \Bbb R^+$.

I tried the D Alambert convergence test but the result of limes is 1, so this test does not say anything about the convergence of the sum. Is this harmonic/hyperharmonic term of the sum crucial, how to approach the problem?
According to my calculation $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1
$$
Which convergence test to apply, or whether there is any transformation of the expression that will give the answer?

Try Raabe test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test

Sorry, but previously asked here

I think as long as $b>a$, the sum converges. But I only have a heuristic proof.

For a natural number $a>0$, $$ \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n-1)}{n!} \sim n^{a-1}.$$
Therefore the given sum converges iff $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{b-a+1}}$$ converges, which is the case when $b-a>0$.
Edit: The asymptotic equivalence can be seen as follows: \begin{align}\frac{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n-1)}{n!} &= \frac{1}{(a-1)!}\frac{(n+(a-1))!}{n!} \\&= \frac{1}{(a-1)!}(n+1)\cdots(n+a-1) \end{align}
Since $(n+1)\cdots(n+a-1)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of order $a-1$, the result follows.

\begin{align}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}&=\frac{n+1}{n+a}\left(1+\frac 1 n \right)^b=\left(1+\frac a n \right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac 1 n \right)^{b+1}=\\
&=\left(1-\frac a n+ o\left(\frac 1 n\right) \right)\left(1+\frac{b+1}{n} +o\left(\frac 1 n\right)\right)=\\
&=1+\frac{b-a+1}{n} +o\left(\frac 1 n\right)\end{align}
Then use Raabe from comment- hope you can carry out the omitted transformations yourself and draw a conclusion.
